# How can i get the nearest upper value from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have a database with different values for weight charges, if the total weight is forexample 2.5 kg so i want to put a condition which pick the nearest upper value from the database, like 3kg charges if avaivalbe.

I have this code, on the basis of Total weight i want to pick the nearest upper values charges and cost of total weight:

```
public ActionResult LoadweightByServices(int service_id, float totalweight) { 
    OrderModel om = new OrderModel();                  
    Subcategory_ _Subcategory = new Subcategory_(); 
    var we = om.Get_Shipping_weight(service_id).ToList(); 
    double? weight = we.SingleOrDefault().Weight; 
    if (totalweight == weight || totalweight < weight) 
    { 
    float? cost=we.SingleOrDefault().Cost; 
    float? charge=we.SingleOrDefault().Charge; 
    } 

    return View()
     }
```

Comment: Some code would be useful. How are dealing with database - directly, entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CEILING` function.

Eg `Select Ceiling(1.1)` returns 2

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)

> Returns the smallest integer greater than, or equal to, the specified numeric expression.

In your code, try

```
weight = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimel(we.SingleOrDefault().Weight));
```

Comment: I have this code, on the basis of Total weight i want to pick the nearest upper values charges and cost of  total weight:


public JsonResult LoadweightByServices(int service_id, float totalweight)
{
OrderModel om = new OrderModel();
Subcategory_ _Subcategory = new Subcategory_();

var we = om.Get_Shipping_weight(service_id).ToList();


double? weight = we.SingleOrDefault().Weight;
if (totalweight == weight || totalweight < weight)
{

float? cost=we.SingleOrDefault().Cost;
float? charge=we.SingleOrDefault().Charge;


}



return View()

Comment: Add this code to your question and format it properly

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult LoadweightByServices(int service_id, float totalweight) { 
OrderModel om = new OrderModel();                  
Subcategory_ _Subcategory = new Subcategory_(); 
var we = om.Get_Shipping_weight(service_id).ToList(); 
double? weight = we.SingleOrDefault().Weight; 
if (Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(totalweight)) == weight || Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(totalweight)) < weight) 
{ 
float? cost=we.SingleOrDefault().Cost; 
float? charge=we.SingleOrDefault().Charge; 
} 

return View()
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I am doing it in ASP.Net MVC

Comment: @Hamadkhan, SQL side use ROUND() or C# side use Math.Round()

Comment: I have this code, on the basis of Total weight i want to pick the nearest upper values charges and cost of  total weight:


public JsonResult LoadweightByServices(int service_id, float totalweight)
{
OrderModel om = new OrderModel();
Subcategory_ _Subcategory = new Subcategory_();

var we = om.Get_Shipping_weight(service_id).ToList();


double? weight = we.SingleOrDefault().Weight;
if (totalweight == weight || totalweight < weight)
{

float? cost=we.SingleOrDefault().Cost;
float? charge=we.SingleOrDefault().Charge;


}



return View()

Comment: @Hamadkhan, put this code into your question with formatting.

Comment: Please check it the above question, i have added my code

Comment: @Hamadkhan, I have added my answer.